# ColdFusion Builder - Open project

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

This might sound very very basic 101 type question, but I really need help on this. I am a .net background developer, and recently received an existing project's code which is in ColdFusion. I want to open this existing code in CF Builder.

I installed prequisites like ColdFusion developer edition and ColdFusion builder. In visual studio, we do this thing either by double click on the csproj file in the explorer or from File > Open menu and selecting project. In CF Builder I don't see that option at all. In the code there are files with CFM and CFC extension, Two LCK files. In the builder, there is no Open Project option (There is one inside Project menu but that's always disabled) . I also tried Import project but no luck. Any help? I am using CF Builder 2 trial version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to import your project with the following steps:

1. File -> Import
2. Other -> Existing Folder as New Project
3. Select the folder and provide a project name (this is internal to the IDE only)
4. Let CFBuilder do it's thing importing
5. Once imported, the new project will appear in your Project View
6. Right click on the project folder in this view and select Apply CF Nature

That should have your CFML project imported into the IDE and 'tagged' as a CFML project.

Comment: Appreciate the help. I did try to import, but I had not tried to go through "Other" option. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you don't mind, it would be very great, if you could point me to some basic getting started kind of links for both CF and Builder. I would be able to pick it up from there..

Comment: You bet: http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/getting-started-adobe (ref card on CFB) and http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/cfbuilder_gettingstarted.html (Adobe article on getting started with CFB) and http://www.sagarganatra.com/2011/03/cheat-sheet-of-keyboard-shortcuts-in.html (keyboard shortcut cheat sheet) and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DD78zUgdVzU (a little dated but still decent). Hope that helps!

Comment: Crap! Forgot to add a really good resource for learning CFML: http://bittersweetryan.github.com/ColdFusion-Koans/ (the Koans project is such a good and quick way to learn CF, especially since you already have a dev background!).

Comment: When I try this method, it creates another folder within the directory that I selected with the project name. Therefore, none of my code is actually imported into the project. I also tried to select the folder above and name the project I actually wanted it to import, but it gave me an error when I did that.